# How to delete specific elements in a list

Tags: r

I have a list:

```
aa <- list(c(12, 1, 5, 4), c(2, 3, 5), c(6, 4,1))
aa
#[[1]]
#[1] 12  1  5  4

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3 5

#[[3]]
#[1] 6 4 1
```

I would like to delete all "4" and "5" in aa and be able to return the following list:

```
#[[1]]
#[1] 12  1

#[[2]]
#[1] 2 3

#[[3]]
#[1] 6 1
```

So is there a simple way of doing this? Thank you.

Comment: similar to @BigDataScientist solution: `lapply(aa, function(x)x[!x %in% c(4,5)])`

Comment: @BigDataScientist, you should note that if there can be duplicates in the list's elements, `setdiff` will remove those and only return the set

Comment: good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have a simple solution using `lapply`:

```
lapply(aa, function(x) {x[!(x %in% c(4, 5))]})
```

**Output:**

```
[[1]]
[1] 12  1

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 6 1
```

Comment: Another option is `library(purrr); aa %>% map(~ .[!. %in% c(4, 5)])`

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated!